# Plot/graph/chart generalized language, schema or API

Tags: charts, matplotlib

I swear at some point I ran across a project to come up with a generalized schema to describe (plots|graphs|charts). But I can't seem to dig it up in google now. The idea was that every plotting package (e.g. Matlab, ggplot, plotly, matplotlib) has their own API. The project was trying to define a rational and consistent one that could be used in general.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

https://vega.github.io/vega/

I think this is a great idea. I'd love to see something like this be a standard, with other packages acting as wrappers. But I haven't investigated to see how robust this is yet relative to `ggplot2` or `plotly.js` or Matlab.

Comment: Interesting, I'll add it to my list of things to learn :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [The Grammar of Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387245448), which is what `ggplot2` is based on?

Comment: Looks interesting, but that's not it. It is a project with a website, and maybe even a github repository.

Comment: Ah! Remembering that it had a github repo allowed me to find it! https://vega.github.io/vega/